# Application Icons In the Menu Bar & the Ability To Choose Which Are Active Upon Startup of my Mac?

Tags: macos

Are the application icons located towards the right side of the menu bar next to system icons automatically active upon boot up of an Apple Mac. What decides which apps sit there & is there a way to choose which apps are active and sit in the menu bar by default at startup ?

Indeed if one is using a 13″ MacBook Pro (like myself) or even an 11″ MacBook Air, what happens when the number of apps gets to the extent where they begin to close the gap towards what I believe is usually **Help** located towards the left of the menu bar. If your using a 27″ display I guess this scenario doesnt occur.

Is there a way to minimise those apps in the menu bar whilst keeping them active if required ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You decide which non-system apps you want there. If you want them removed: hold down <kbd>command</kbd>, click the icon and drag it off of the menu bar. They can be re-ordered by dragging them to different positions instead of off the menu bar.

You can also add/remove them from start-up in the Login Items menu (System Preferences>Accounts, click *YourUserName* and choose the Login Items tab).

Comment: Sounds good, and obviously free. I'll have to try it. Thx :)

Answer (score 0):

There is an App available called Bartender, so i'm told (albeit not free), which deals with the apps located in the menu bar. Hope this helps other people who maybe in a similar situation

http://www.macbartender.com/